# Django filter geometry given a coordinate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postgis, django-postgresql

I want to get a row from a postgis table given a coordinate/point. With raw sql I do it with:

```
SELECT * FROM parcelas 
WHERE fk_area=152 
AND ST_contains(geometry,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(342884.86705619487, 6539464.45201204),32721));
```

The query before returns one row.

When I try to do this on django it doesn't return me any row:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pnt = GEOSGeometry('POINT(342884.86705619487 6539464.45201204)', srid=32721)
        parcelas = Parcelas.objects.filter(fk_area=152,geometry__contains=pnt)

        #Also tried this
        #parcelas = Parcelas.objects.filter(fk_area=pk,geometry__contains='SRID=32721;POINT(342884.86705619487 6539464.45201204)')

        serializer = ParcelasSerializer(parcelas, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Even with django raw query it fails although in this case it returns me an internal server error (argument 3: class 'TypeError': wrong type):

```
class TestView(APIView):
        def get(self, request, format=None):
            parcelas = Parcelas.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM parcelas WHERE fk_area=152 AND ST_contains(geometry,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(342884.86705619487, 6539464.45201204),32721))')
            for p in parcelas:
                #Internal server error
                print(p.id)

        return Response('Test')
```

My model parcelas look like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Parcelas(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    fk_area = models.ForeignKey(Areas, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_area')
    geometry = models.GeometryField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'parcelas'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrongly if someone has any idea.

EDIT:

If I print the raw query that django made:

```
SELECT "parcelas"."id", "parcelas"."fk_area", "parcelas"."geometry"::bytea FROM "parcelas" WHERE ("parcelas"."fk_area" = 152 AND ST_Contains("parcelas"."geometry", ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromEWKB('\001\001\000\000 \321\177\000\000C\224\335w\223\355\024A\350\303\355\0342\362XA'::bytea), 4326)))
```

Seems like django is not converting it to the correct srid (32721) but I don't know why

EDIT 2:

If in my model I specify the SRID it works correctly:

```
class Parcelas(models.Model):
    geometry = models.GeometryField(srid=32721)
```

The problem is that the SRID can be variable depending on the query the rows have one SRID or another so I don't want to set it to always being one.

Comment: If you print the desired object (by filtering it by its `id`, if possible) what does the `geometry` value prints? I'm just guessing, but maybe Django is saving the coordinates values slightly different.

Comment: It prints "SRID=32721;POLYGON ((342416.32 6539436.85, 342415.73 6539437.1, ..." (it has many points). I think the problem is the SRID django is using the srid 4326 to filter but I dont know how to change it.

Comment: Okay, so it seems like your problem is doing the filtering like `geometry__contains`. Take a look at [dwithin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-dwithin) to see if that helps

Comment: I have seen dwithin but it is to filter geometries which are near. In my case I want to filter geometries which are one inside another (point inside polygon). The problem is related with SRID see my edit 2

Answer (score 1):

Test database is created separately and does not contain the same data as the main application database. Try using `pdb` and listing all entries inside the `parcelas` table. Unless `TestView` means just a mock view for the time being.

Using `pdb`:

```
   import pdb, pdb.set_trace()
   Parcelas.objects.all()
```

Comment: Yes TestView is a temporal view I made for this example on my local computer that is pointing to the same database as the raw query I made directly in the database

Answer (score 0):

In case the records geometry needs to be compared to a geojson like object one approach is to convert the object to `GEOSGeometry` and then find the record using `.get()`, `.filter()` etc.

For example, in case of an API JSON request payload that contains somewhere in the payload the following field:

```
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
                [21.870314, 39.390873],
                [21.871913, 39.39319],
                [21.874029, 39.392443],
                [21.873401, 39.391328],
                [21.873369, 39.391272],
                [21.873314, 39.391171],
                [21.872715, 39.390024],
                [21.870314, 39.390873]
        ]
    ]
}
```

One can use the following code:

```
import json

from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

# Assuming the python dictionary containing the geometry field is geometry_dict
payload_geometry = GEOSGeometry(json.dumps(geometry_dict))

parcel = Parcel.objects.get(geometry=payload_geometry)
```